# repo snc error fatal: Could not read bundle

Tags: android, clone, bundle, synchronization, repository

I am trying to sync a list of android repo's after doing git clone and repo init.

I ran the repo sync command and enabled traces.

The traces show the following error:

```
fatal: Could not read bundle
```

The repo sync doesn't work or return, despite leaving it overnight.

Could someone throw light on any similar error they faced earlier and what they did to solve it?

Comment: This got solved. I reinstalled and configured repo tool once again. I guess it was because of some mismatch in the checksum of repo tool that my repo sync failed.

Running repo --trace sync really helps in understanding the current git file being synchronized and accurate progress.